# BFS Implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, breadth-first-search

```
def bfs(graph, root):
    visited, queue = [], [root]
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.pop(0)
        for w in graph[vertex]:
            if w not in visited:
                visited.append(w)
                queue.append(w)

graph = {0: [1, 2], 1: [2], 2: []}
bfs(graph, 0)
```

Does this look like a correct implementation of BFS in Python 3?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- `set`s perform containing checks (`w in visited`) \$O(1)\$ rather than \$O(n)\$ for lists.
- [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) are better than lists for poping elements at the front (`popleft`).
- you should put your example code under an `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause.
- `w` as a variable name does not convey meaning, you should try to come up with something more explicit.

```
import collections


def breadth_first_search(graph, root): 
    visited, queue = set(), collections.deque([root])
    while queue: 
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]: 
            if neighbour not in visited: 
                visited.add(neighbour) 
                queue.append(neighbour) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = {0: [1, 2], 1: [2], 2: []} 
    breadth_first_search(graph, 0)
```

---

Given a growing number of comments indicating that the code does not return anything, I’d like to add that, yes, this code does not process nodes: it only traverse the graph and you're likely to want to add your own custom logic to process each node. As your mileage may vary (building a traversal list, finding the first node that satisfies a condition, etc.), there is not a "one code fits all" approach, but a useful first approximation would be to `yield` each node as they are traversed:

```
import collections


def breadth_first_search(graph, root): 
    visited, queue = set(), collections.deque([root])
    while queue: 
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        yield vertex
        visited.add(vertex)
        queue.extend(n for n in graph[vertex] if n not in visited)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = {1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [3, 6, 7], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
    list(breadth_first_search(graph, 1))  # [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

Note that this alternative iteration also takes care of the bug mentioned in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/175749/84718)

Comment: But the code is poping elements from the right?

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson Which code? OP uses [`list.pop(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) which pop from the left and mine uses [`deque.popleft()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) which, well, also pop from the left.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be blind. For some reason, I didn't realize OP used 0 as an argument.

Comment: You forgot to 'return visited'

Comment: I'm still grocking this, but it doesn't return anything right?

Comment: @ScottSkiles Right, the idea is to put whatever custom logic between the `for` and the `if` to return the node you're interested in.

Comment: @301_Moved_Permanently, the output of your code is not correct. Take the following graph into consideration: ```test_graph1 = {1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [3, 6, 7], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}```. If the starting vertex is `1`, all its connected components should be displayed first before moving onto the next node (connected components can be displayed in any order). Output of your code: ```{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}``` -- this is wrong, output of OP's code: ```[2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7]``` -- this is right.

Comment: @Saurabh Are you really trying to compare an unordered set with an ordered list? I don't know how you found out these values as the codes don't return anything, but if you only `return visited` at the end, you loose any information about order. Try to `print('examining', vertex)` right after the pop and before the for, you’ll see that the order is exactly the same.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Mathias Ettinger's use of `set`s and `deque`s, with two changes:

- name the set `seen` instead of `visited`, because your algorithm adds to set before visiting.
- add the root to `seen` before entering while loop. Otherwise the root may be revisited (eg test case below where 1 points back to 0).

  ```
  import collections

  def bfs(graph, root):
      seen, queue = set([root]), collections.deque([root])
      while queue:
          vertex = queue.popleft()
          visit(vertex)
          for node in graph[vertex]:
              if node not in seen:
                  seen.add(node)
                  queue.append(node)

  def visit(n):
      print(n)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      graph = {0: [1, 2], 1: [2, 0], 2: []} 
      bfs(graph, 0)
  ```

  Outputs:

  ```
  0
  1
  2
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to explore the vertex completely before moving onto the next vertex. For the below adjacency matrix:

```
test_graph = {
    1: [2, 4, 5],
    2: [3, 6, 7],
    3: [],
    4: [],
    5: [],
    6: [],
    7: []
}
```

The output should be `1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3`, or `1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7`, etc. The idea is that the current vertex should be **completely explored** before moving onto the next vertex. In addition, **connected vertices can occur in any order**.

Below code provides the correct sequence

```
import collections

def bfs(graph, start_vertex):
    visited = set()
    traversal = []
    queue = collections.deque([start_vertex])
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            traversal.append(vertex)
            queue.extend(reversed(graph[vertex]))   # add vertex in the same order as visited
    return traversal
```